# Eliminar descuadres y celdas vacias, Dynamic Reports

Tags: java

Tengo un problema y es que no consigo eliminar los descuadres que se producen en mi tabla ni tampoco como eliminar las celdas vacias

Esta es la configuracion de mis `crosstable`

```
CrosstabRowGroupBuilder<String> rowGroup = ctab.rowGroup("filas", String.class).setShowTotal(false);
        listaRowGroup.add(rowGroup);



        CrosstabColumnGroupBuilder<String> columnGroupprin = ctab.columnGroup("principal", String.class).setShowTotal(false);
        listaColumnGroup.add(columnGroupprin);

        CrosstabVariableBuilder<String> unitPriceVariable = ctab.variable("generic", String.class, Calculation.SUM);
        listaVariablesstring.add(unitPriceVariable);
        CrosstabVariableBuilder<String> priceVariable = ctab.variable(new GenericExpressionString(), Calculation.SUM);
        listaVariablesstring.add(priceVariable);

        CrosstabMeasureBuilder<String> quantityMeasure = ctab.measure("Mes", "genericvar", String.class, Calculation.SUM);
        listaMeasuresstring.add(quantityMeasure);
        CrosstabMeasureBuilder<String> priceMeasure1 = ctab.measure("Acum", new GenericVariable1ExpressionString(unitPriceVariable));
        listaMeasuresstring.add(priceMeasure1);
```

Aqui el `builder`

```
CrosstabBuilder crearCrossTabConHeader(int width, int height) {

        //Creamos el crossTab referente a los datos que nos llegan de la tabla en cuestion
        CrosstabBuilder crosstab = ctab.crosstab()
                //.headerCell(cmp.text("").setStyle(Templates.prueba2))
              //  .addHeaderCell(cmp.text(this.getHeaderCell()).setStyle(Templates.prueba))
               // .addHeaderCell(cmp.text("").setStyle(Templates.prueba3))
                .setCellWidth(width)
                .setCellHeight(height)
                .setDataPreSorted(true);
        for(int i=0;i<this.getListaRowGroup().size();i++) {
            crosstab.addRowGroup(this.getListaRowGroup().get(i));
        }
        for(int j=0;j<this.getListaColumnGroup().size();j++) {
            crosstab.addColumnGroup(this.getListaColumnGroup().get(j));
        }
        for(int k=0;k<this.getListaMeasures().size();k++) {
            crosstab.addMeasure(this.getListaMeasures().get(k));
        }
        for(int l=0;l<this.getListaVariables().size();l++) {
            crosstab.addVariable(this.getListaVariables().get(l));
        }
        for(int k=0;k<this.getListaMeasuresstring().size();k++) {
            crosstab.addMeasure(this.getListaMeasuresstring().get(k));
        }
        for(int l=0;l<this.getListaMeasuresMill().size();l++) {
            crosstab.addMeasure(this.getListaMeasuresMill().get(l));
        }
        for(int l=0;l<this.getListaVariablesstring().size();l++) {
            crosstab.addVariable(this.getListaVariablesstring().get(l));
        }
        for(int l=0;l<this.getListaVariablesMill().size();l++) {
            crosstab.addVariable(this.getListaVariablesMill().get(l));
        }   
        return crosstab;
```

Y aqui un ejemplo del `datasource`:

```
dataSource.add("Pepe","Accidentes","Maniobra","0","0");
dataSource.add("Pepe","Nº Relativo (M. Km-Tren)","","0","0");
```

Como veis en la imagen,la primera fila no esta pegada a la segunda y debajo de total se crea una celda en blanco que no quiero,me gustaria saber si puedo eliminar de alguna manera eso

[image: Dos celdas en blanco y una linea de espacio debajo de total]

Comment: Para los estilos utilizo la libreria `Style Builder`